# Convert mootools code to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have a slider and I'm manipulating it's color and gradient.

It uses mootools and everything works fine.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/R9nyW/84/)**</kbd>

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputs = Array.splice(inputs, 0);
inputs.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.type === 'range') {
        item.onchange = function () {
            value = (item.value - item.min)/(item.max - item.min)
            item.style.backgroundImage = [
                '-webkit-gradient(',
                  'linear, ',
                  'left top, ',
                  'right top, ',
                  'color-stop(' + value + ', #0B8CDD), ',
                  'color-stop(' + value + ', #898989)',
                ')'
            ].join('');
        };
    }
});
```

**I want to convert the Mootools js code to Js/Jquery.**

Please help me out.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EDW5h/2/

Comment: also please go through the basics of jQuery and selectors http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Use [element](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector) and [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to target the `input type="range"` elements, use the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) method to register change event handler then use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) to set the css properties

```
$('input[type="range"]').change(function () {
    //`this` inside the handler refers to the current input element
    var value = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min);
    //use `.css()` to set the css properties
    $(this).css('backgroundImage', [
        '-webkit-gradient(',
        'linear, ',
        'left top, ',
        'right top, ',
        'color-stop(' + value + ', #0B8CDD), ',
        'color-stop(' + value + ', #898989)',
        ')'].join(''));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EDW5h/)

Answer (score 1):

If the Mootools works, why to change?

**plain javascript:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var item = inputs[i];
    item.addEventListener('change', function () {
        value = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)
        this.style.backgroundImage = [
            '-webkit-gradient(',
            'linear, ',
            'left top, ',
            'right top, ',
            'color-stop(' + value + ', #0B8CDD), ',
            'color-stop(' + value + ', #898989)',
            ')'].join('');
    });
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxPQu/)

---

Here is **another version**, with very litle jQuery:

```
$('input[type="range"]').change(function () {
    value = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min)
    this.style.backgroundImage = [
        '-webkit-gradient(',
        'linear, ',
        'left top, ',
        'right top, ',
        'color-stop(' + value + ', #0B8CDD), ',
        'color-stop(' + value + ', #898989)',
        ')'].join('');
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwnYq/)

Comment: Thanks @Sergio! Actually, rest of my project code is in Jquery and I was getting errors in porting this code-snippet from Mootools to Jquery, which I coded earlier. :)

Comment: Bit confused, which answer to accept :) How to know which one was faster? hah!

Comment: @softvar, Arun answered first :) I answered with a faster performing solution :) Choose the one you want, it doesn't matter.